# spring mvc not able to display my page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having problem when displaying new page from controller.
Here when I return ModelAndView object it come to login page(login.jsp) but when I return string it display correct page (admin.jsp).

Returning ModelAndView.

```
if (bean.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase("rohit") && bean.getPassWord().equalsIgnoreCase("rawat"))
{
    AdminHomeBean admin = new AdminHomeBean();
    return new ModelAndView("admin/admin", "adminHbean", admin);
}
else
{
    bean.setErrorMsg("User Name or Password is Incorret");
    return new ModelAndView("login/login", "loginbean", bean); 
}
```

This method always returns the login page.

Return String.

`return "admin/admin";`

This works fine, and return admin page.

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is not going to the else part always ?

Comment: yes.. m sure.. when it goes to else part i see message on screen..

Comment: it is not even looking for the return statement..

Comment: how your view resolver is configured??

Comment: <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

Comment: its not logical, when the modelAndView for else is directing to the right page then either you have a broken or not valid jsp in the location admin/admin or your if condtion is always evaluating to false, so not executing the return to admin/admin.

Comment: if  it is not going in 'if'  condition then it also show the message.. I debugged it . it is going in if condition but return on same page.. i build workspace also.:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually was importing wrong modelandview.

instead of org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView i was importing org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView.

And both have their own binding process.

Thanks guys..